# Computational complexity of zeros of an analytic function

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, na.numerical-analysis, computability-theory, computer-science

[The work of Friedman and Ko, page 342, Corollary 4.3.1](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81983170.pdf)
states that all zeros of analytic polynomial time computable function are polynomial time computable, but for me that is not clear how it could be performed or it just means that such an algorithm should exist? Is it an approximation of a zero and does that means that if an analytic function has values, close to zero they would also be accepted as zeros if we do not use high precision?

Comment: To say that a real number is computable means that there is a computable procedure to compute rational approximations to it within a given rational error. And similarly with polynomial time computable (polynomial time in the given error). One doesn't compute just one approximation and then accept that as completed, but rather, the point is that the computable procedure can continue with further approximations, as accurate as desired.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, if we have an oscillating function that exhibits multiple real zeros within a certain interval, and also includes points where the function value approaches but does not exactly reach zero within the same interval, how would a computational procedure behave in this context? Specifically,  will it accurately compute all the real zeros? And, in cases where the function value is close to but not exactly zero, will these points be erroneously accepted as zeros if the precision of the approximation is not sufficiently high in the current computational step?

Comment: My point is about what it means to say that a zero is computable. You seem to be thinking that the computational process must be using something like Newton's method or using the function itself as a kind of oracle, but that is not necessarily how the zero is computed. For example, every algebraic number is computable in the sense I have described, but there are subtle issues of uniformity involving the type of behavior you describe. The main point I am trying to make is to be clear on what it means to say that a zero is computable.

Comment: The concept of computable real number stems from Alan Turing's 1936 paper with that concept in the title. (Although his original conception wasn't quite right--see https://jdh.hamkins.org/alan-turing-on-computable-numbers.)